# ASP.NET MVC SEO URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, seo

My goal is to have the url routing as following:

```
http://www.abc.com/this-is-peter-page

http://www.abc.com/this-is-john-page
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this without placing controller name an function name in the url above? If page above not found, I should redirect to 404 page.

Addon 1: this-is-peter-page and this-is-john-page is not static content, but is from database.

Comment: Is "this-is-peter-page" a static page or a dynamic one where "this-is-peter-page" would be a field in a database?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similar to KingNestor's implementation, you can also do the followings which will ease your work:

1) Write Your Model

```
public class MyUser{public String UserName{get; set;}}
```

2) add route to global asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "NameRouting",
   "{name}",
   new { controller = "PersonalPage", action = "Index", username="name" });
```

3) Roll your own custom model binder derived from IModelBinder

```
public class CustomBinder : IModelBinder
    {
       public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
       {
          var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
          var username = getUserNameFromDashedString(request["username"]);
          MyUser user = new MyUser(username);

          return user;
       }
    }
```

4) in your action:

```
public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomBinder))] MyUser usr)
{
    ViewData["Welcome"] = "Viewing " + usr.Username;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks to Zhaph for re-arrange step 3 and step 4

Comment: I found bindingContext doesn't containing HttpContext

Answer (score 4):

I personally wouldn't suggest a route like that but if it meets your needs you need to do something like:

Have the following route in your Global.asax file:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
       "NameRouting",
       "{name}",
       new { controller = "PersonalPage", action = "routeByName" });
```

Then, in your "PersonalPageController", have the following method:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult routeByName(string name)
    {
         switch (name)
         {
             case "this-is-peter-page": return View("PeterView");
             case "this-is-john-page": return View("JohnView");
             case Default: return View("NotFound");
         }
    }
```

Make sure you have the appropriate views: "PeterView", "JohnView" and "NotFound" in your *Views/PersonalPage/*.

Comment: You could combine that with a route constraint to prevent 'unwanted' requests to go to that controller. (I assume that you still need some other controller)

Comment: how to prevent 'unwanted' request?

Comment: @Ervin Ter, you can provide route constraints that constrain this route to a particular regular expression.

Comment: @Simucal, I see. Never know that we can plant regular expression on route.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be done. AFAIK ASP.NET MVC recognizes routing parameters via the character "/".

Your format, on the other hand, goes by "{controller}-is-{id}-{action}" -- so there is no way the controller can be distinguished from the id and the action.

I think using "/" characters doesn't affect or degrade SEO; it only affects human readability and retention of the URL.

Anyway, the following URL is possible: `http://www.abc.com/this-is-the-page-of/Peter` by adding another route in the `Global.asax` RegisterRoutes method:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "AnotherRoute",
            "this-is-the-page-of/{id}",
            new { controller = "PersonalPage", action = "Details", id = "" }
        );
```

...assuming that `PersonalPageController` implements a Details ActionResult method that points to the desired page.